# Wget entire http directory that is password protected

Tags: ssh, wget

I am trying to back up one of my sites that is password protected using wget. I can't seem to format the command correctly because I keep getting 401 errors:

```
wget http://dev.example.com/"Login?mode=login
> &user-username=TYPEUSERNAMEHERE&user-password=TYPEPASSWORDHERE"
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? What is the correct way to download an entire directory that is password protected using wget? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the password protection is by htaccess you have to form your url like

```
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@Domain.
```

Answer (score 5):

Wait I got it:

```
wget -r --http-user=USERNAME --http-passwd='PASSWORD'
```